# Date format Error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass data into a database in `MM/DD/yyyy` format and need to extract time.

The other formats should not take.

I am using the code

```
double intakeDate = double.Parse(dtexcelupload.Rows[rowindex]["JoinDate"].ToStri‌​ng()); 
DateTime requiredDate = DateTime.FromOADate(intakeDate);
```

Comment: What time do you expect in a date of format `MM/DD/yyyy`? Please enhance your question, because in this form it is near uncomprehensible and it's not clear what you even want.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What is the code you're using? What is the expected outcome? Can you make a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Don't pass dates in a format to the database, use parametrized queries to avoid sql-injection and localization issues. So pass it as a `DateTime`-parameter.

Comment: Why do you need to send anything to the *DB* in a format at all? You should send it as the `DateTime` type, which doesn't *have* a format. Don't use string concatenation to build your SQL, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Like `Lasse` said no need to format in that way. Use `DateTime` type.

Comment: I have Date column in excel . I can upload the excel with MM/dd/yyyy format with out error.while uploading excel with all other format

Comment: i am getting error

Comment: I am using the code  double intakeDate = double.Parse(dtexcelupload.Rows[rowindex]["JoinDate"].ToString());
                DateTime requiredDate = DateTime.FromOADate(intakeDate);

Comment: @keerthi why are you trying to parse a date as a `double`? That makes no sense. use `DateTime.Parse()`. Or use `DateTime.TryParse()` if you and check the return value, if you don't want to handle an exception. If you want to specify a precise format, use `DateTime.ParseExact()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()` respectively.

Comment: Hi it is working fine now thanks.But while entering any letters  For example Abc iam getting error "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParse` if you expect invalid strings.